# In the iOS SDK (Swift 3.0), Firebase Database Queries that make use of "queryOrdered/queryEqual", don't work as expected

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When running the code below, I get an empty response, even though the corresponding data is there:

```
self.ref?.child("play-data/calories/GC5g4RUmy0WTTL5w3jSobefa9Ft2").
queryOrdered(byChild: "parentId").
queryEqual(toValue: "-KcpS62MR-73MozKJEVt").
observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print("ITEMS \(snapshot.childrenCount)")
        }) { (error) in
            print("ERROR :: \(error)")
        }
```

The data looks like this:

```
{
  "play-data" : {
    "calories" : {
      "GC5g4RUmy0WTTL5w3jSobefa9Ft2" : {
        "-KcpTSo0KrnNIzmAAD9O" : {
          "endTime" : 1486955567572,
          "id" : "-KcpTSo0KrnNIzmAAD9O",
          "parentId" : "-KcpS62MR-73MozKJEVt",
          "startTime" : 1486955550331,
          "value" : 1.328500509262085
        },
        "-KcpTT---0Zu-0eTd4a8" : {
          "endTime" : 1486955627572,
          "id" : "-KcpTT---0Zu-0eTd4a8",
          "parentId" : "-KcpS62MR-73MozKJEVt",
          "startTime" : 1486955567572,
          "value" : 4.62333345413208
        },
        "-KcpTT-1SvZrScKdceLC" : {
          "endTime" : 1486955636994,
          "id" : "-KcpTT-1SvZrScKdceLC",
          "parentId" : "-KcpS62MR-73MozKJEVt",
          "startTime" : 1486955627572,
          "value" : 0.7260898947715759
        }
      }
    }
```

So based on the data, it should print 3 but does 0. Permissions are configured correctly since I have Android and web implementations that work fine with this data. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, looks like this was the result of my local and cloud versions of the data being out of sync and therefore the inconsistent results during testing (where I had to run tests, replace the post-test data with an older backup, repeat) I fixed these issues by adding this line to my init code:

```
ref?.child("play-data").keepSynced(true)
```

I already had this one before:

```
db?.persistenceEnabled = true
```

Where **ref** and **db** are references to FIRDatabaseReference/FIRDatabase.